# IF statement containing both AND and OR

Tags: development

Here is the gist of what I want to do.  Hoping someone can help.

`=IF ([value1]="" OR [value1]="Select") AND [value2]="" THEN [value3]="" ELSE [value3]="assigned value"`

I can get this close without the OR inserted but don't know how to get that part into the function.  Here's what I have now without the OR part:

`=IF(AND([value1]="Select",[value2]=""),"",[value3])`

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be the below:

```
=IF(AND(OR([value1]="Select", [value1]=""),[value2]=""),"",[value3])
```

You can test it in Excel, it should be the same.

Comment: Thank you Joanne - I thought I had my code exactly like this previously but it didn't work so I posted the question. I must have had my syntax slightly off.  Your version above worked great - thanks very much!!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as accepted if this resolved your problem!